# Getting value true/false from checkbox on Eureka after submitting form via button

Tags: swift, realm, eureka-forms

I am trying to pull all values from a form into Realm upon hitting a button. I've figured out how to pull the text value, as so:

```
<<< TextRow(){ row in
                row.title = "Referrals Out"
                row.placeholder = "4"
                row.onCellHighlightChanged({ (cell, row) in
                    if row.isHighlighted == false {
                        self.planTitle = row.value ?? ""
                        print(self.planTitle)
                    }
                }).cellSetup() {cell, row in
                    cell.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Noto Sans Kannada", size:15)
                }
            }
```

I am trying same, and have tried anything I could think of, including tag = title, but cannot get the value of the checkbox as a bool - true/false.  Here is what I have for the checkbox:

```
<<< CheckRow(){ row in
            row.title = row.tag
            row.title = "Referrals Out"
            row.value = false
            row.onCellHighlightChanged({ (cell, row) in
                if row.isHighlighted == false {
                    self.referralsOut = row.value ?? false
                }
            })
        }
```

The button is working well to pull the text value, but cannot get the checkbox value. When I add in print(value) for the checkbox, it will print the value on page load, but not after I change the value of the checkmark to true or false, etc.

Any help greatly appreciate!!!

Answer (score 1):

To get the value *after I change* there is the `.onChange` modifier

```
<<< CheckRow(){ row in
    row.title = row.tag
    row.title = "Referrals Out"
    row.value = false
    row.onCellHighlightChanged({ (cell, row) in
        if row.isHighlighted == false {
            self.referralsOut = row.value ?? false
        }
    }).onChange { row in
        print(row.value!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Vadian!! When I save it to the Object, it is not saving it as true/false, rather it records 1.

My object:
class Plan: Object {
    [at]objc dynamic var planTitle: String = ""
    [at]objc dynamic var transactionGoal: Double = 0.00
    [at]objc dynamic var volumeGoal: String = ""
    [at]objc dynamic var referralsOut: Bool = false

}

And the output:

Plan {
 planTitle = ;
 transactionGoal = 0;
 volumeGoal = ;
 referralsOut = 1;
}

But in the console, it does show true or false. [at] is actually the "at" sign.

Really appreciate the help!!

Comment: I have no idea what *save it to the Object* means.

Comment: I have a Realm object I was trying to save the Bool referralsOut response to... but, I just figured out that rather than saving as true or false, it is saving as 0 or 1. So all good. Thanks again for your help.